# Dereferencing pointer in Code Composer Studio

Tags: c++, pointers, code-composer

I have a value I receive in an unsigned byte array that I would like to dereference as a float.  Take ptr as a uint8_t* pointing at a byte array of four values 0,0,0xCD,0x42 (this is a little endian system).

```
float val = *(float*)ptr;
```

is return -1.34e8

When I type:

```
*(float*)ptr;
```

In the expressions window after hitting a break point in that section of code, it gives me 102.5 as expected.  Further, when I type:

```
*(float*)(ptr - 1);
```

I get the incorrect -1.34e8, as if the compiler used ptr - 1 instead of what I typed.

I'm confused - am I missing something here?

Comment: Basically the deref is correct.  if you printf("%p", ptr); do you get an address that is maybe not 4-byte aligned (or at least 2-byte)?  (This may be necessary on some platforms).  And btw, (ptr-1) is one byte back (because it's a uint8_t *), not the usual going back one float-size.

Comment: Yes that's the weird thing.  ptr - 1 is one byte back, so it's as if my original code *(float*)ptr; is looking one byte back and interpreting the four float bytes from there instead of from ptr.  My point was that when the code was stopped in the debugger, *(float*)ptr gives me what I expected to get at runtime, and *(float*)(ptr-1) gives me what I actually got at runtime.

Comment: maybe the compiler is rounding the ptr value if it is not aligned correctly.  try printf("%p", ptr); in the source and then check if the result is the same the debugger gives you (just printing the pointer itself in the dbg).

Comment: also, for test, just pass the value of a real float in the uint8_t*, e.g. float f= 102.5;  yourfunct((uint8_t*)&f); and see if that works.

Comment: I did the printf, went to the location in memory and verified that it's pointing at the first 0.  That matches the debugger but the values are still different.  But I think it must be an alignment thing because dereferencing ptr + 1 is still giving me the equivalent of ptr - 1.  Is it normal for compilers to do this or is this just another case of CCS being a nightmare to use?

Comment: Looks like it was alignment after all, thanks!  Passing in a float worked even though the values were identical at the byte level, and I noticed that the float was at an even address and the array an odd.  You should put that in an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the deref is correct.

If you `printf("%p", ptr);` do you get an address that is maybe not 4-byte aligned (or at least 2-byte aligned)? This may be necessary on some platforms.

For test, just pass the value of a real float in the uint8_t*, e.g.

```
float f= 102.5; 
yourfunct((uint8_t*)&f);
```

and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

```
*(float*)(ptr - 1);
```

is the same as this

```
ptr--; //move the pointer to point to charackter in front of the previous one
*(float*)ptr;
```

Is this your intention ?
Or do you just want to subtract 1 from the value that is being pointed to be ptr.

Comment: I don't want to subtract from it.  What I was saying is that during runtime dereferencing ptr as a float is acting as if I had dereferenced the pointer back one byte.